# RescueTime asks for first time login every time Ubuntu starts

Tags: bash, password, startup, startup-applications

I love the RescueTime productivity app. I use the browser version and the desktop version of RescueTime to track my activities. As you might see below, I have RescueTime as one of the applications that will start up with the pc boot.

[image: startup applications window showing RescueTime]

However, every time the PC boots, this window appears:

[image: first time login dialog for RescueTime]

Hence, every time the PC boots I need to put my email and my password.

I wish I could boot my PC without this pain. I tried searching for a bash script to allow me to do that but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Could you help me?

Comment: I think the issue is with the app-implementation. Maybe it's better to contact the developers of the application.

Comment: Could you please verify that your user account has read and write access to all per-user (configuration) files? You can check with the command `find "$HOME" ! \( -user "$USER" -readable -writable \) -ls`. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I say thanks. I used the command you asked. Looking at the terminal's output, I see other applications like Dropbox and SublimeText. I also see stuff related to python (I use this language to program). However, I do not see anything related to RescueTime.

Comment: @Harry: The "other stuff" may actually be the issue. Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of that command? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no bug with the code, this will happen if the application is unable to update its own settings. This would happen when the application's settings file is lacking the "write" permission or the file is owned by the root user.

This sometimes happens and what you need to do is identify the location where this application is saving its settings and do:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER path_to_name_of_file_or_dir
chmod -R u+w path_to_name_of_file_or_dir
```

Without it, the settings never get written. Some applications warn you if they can't write the settings, some don't.

Comment: Thanks @marko. How exactly do I know where is the application saving its settings? Is this dir a possible one: /home/harry/.config/RescueTime.com/log  ?

Comment: I have not used RescueTime so I am unable to answer that question but normally it is in the `.config` folder or in your home directory in a directoty or file with a filename starting with a `.` and the path you given sounds about right. Do: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/harry/.config/RescueTime.com` and `chmod -R u+w /home/harry/.config/RescueTime.com` - assuming that's the right path. Notice: I did not specify the **log** part.

Comment: I did what you said. Am I supposed to see something on the terminal after insertind these commands?  The terminal did not return nothing. Well, at least it didn't return an error message too (which is a good sign). After doing that, I restarted my PC. Again, I inserted my login data. Then, I restarted the PC again. I was expecting to have the problem solved. However, the problem was NOT solved, since I was asked again to input my email and my password. Thanks for the help. Do you suggest something else besides contacting the developer team?

Comment: Hi Harry, the behavior you have described is correct, it is not meant to return anything unless there is an error. One thing I forgot to mention is that once those commands have run, you need to start the program two more times rather than once only and this is because the first time you start it (after the permissions settings have been set), it will attempt to save the settings again and the second time you start it, it will read the settings and it should realize they are there and it shouldn't prompt you again. That is how things normally work.  More on the next comment.

Comment: If this doesn't work for you than all I can suggest is this: Either the path is wrong, the directory is also missing a read permission, it might be a bug.  Try one more command: `chmod -R u+rw /home/harry/.config/RescueTime.com` and launch it twice (no need to restart the PC) and see if it works and if that doesn't work, all I can suggest is to contact the vendor. I suggested all I can think of.

Comment: Hi @marko, thanks for trying to help me. I tried what you said.  Just to guarantee: (i) I inserted the commands you ordered, (ii) I typed "rescuetime" on my terminal to launch the program, (iii) the program opens and I fill with my login data, (iv) I manually closed the program by clicking on the icon and choosing "quit rescue time", (v) again, I launch rescue time on the terminal with "rescuetime".  I repeated the process with the alternative command u+rw... However, it didn't work. Every time I launch the program it asks again for my personal information.

Comment: I am hoping someone else is reading this and would be able to suggest something else. I am out of ideas and the only reason I can think this is happening is: 1. The path `./config/RescueTime.com` is not the one where RT would be saving its settings or 2. a glitch with RT itself. Everything else appears to check out. You can contact the developer and see what they say.